# Retrieving deeply nested ActiveRecord associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, model-associations

I am having trouble figuring out how to retrieve an ActiveRecord object with deeply nested associations. Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve expressed as a JSON object.

Currently, my projects model has:

1. `has_many :groups`
2. `has_many :users, through: :groups`
3. `has_many :members, through: :groups, source: :users`

Expected Result (JSON):

```
{
  "id": 7,
  "name": "Test Project",
  "description": "Project description",
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test Group 1",
      "description": "First test group",
      "members": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Admin",
          "email": "admin@exmaple.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Test User",
          "email": "test@exmaple.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Example Code:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
  has_many :users, through: :groups
  has_many :members, through: :groups, source: :users
end
```

The closest I have managed to the desired result was by adding a groups method to the projects model to get all of the members:

Closest Result (JSON):

```
{
  "id": 7,
  "name": "Test Project",
  "description": "Project description",
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Admin",
      "email": "admin@exmaple.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test User",
      "email": "test@exmaple.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Example Code:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
  has_many :users, through: :groups
  has_many :members, through: :groups, source: :users

  def groups
    members.all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using activemodel serializers to include associated records.

```
class ProjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  has_many :groups 
end

class GroupSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  has_many :members
end
```

You can check it out over at: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

> The has_many, has_one, and belongs_to declarations describe relationships between resources. By default, when you serialize a Post, you will get its Comments as well.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks. We've been using serializers, but I don't think I fully understood them. I mean, I still don't but you've definitely helped me in understanding them in this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcomed. I think you could start by reading what serialization is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization 
> In computer science, in the context of data storage, serialization is the process of translating data structures or object state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link) and reconstructed later in the same or another computer environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
  has_many :users, through: :groups
  has_many :members, through: :groups, source: :users
end

Project.find(7).to_json(include: {groups: {include: :users}})
```